# Avoid double quote confusion when generating CSV files?

Tags: ruby, csv, formatting, string-formatting, export-to-csv

I am pushing some strings to a CSV file:

```
csv_string = CSV.generate({col_sep: ";", row_sep: "\n"}) do |csv|
  csv << ["101-41", "Sparri, \"Violet\" (rod) (1 bunt á 10 stk.)"]
end
```

When the CSV file is finally generated a regular Excel installation will display the content apparently correctly, but a closer look through a plain text editor (like Sublime Text) shows that the double quotes create confusion:

```
10-41;"Sparri, ""Violet"" (rod) (1 bunt á 10 stk.)"
```

How can I avoid this? Should I convert double quotes into something different before pushing to the CSV file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, a double quote is escaped with another double quote. From [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180):

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote.  For example:
>
> ```
> "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
> ```

Comment: OK, so I should simply leave it as it is?

Comment: @ChristofferJoergensen yes, I would leave it as it is. Using a different `quote_char` could cause problems with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is no offical standard, strange as it is.
There are the [RFC 4180 guidelines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2) that state about double quotes

```
5.  Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
       some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
       at all).  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
       double quotes may not appear inside the fields.  For example:

       "aaa","bbb","ccc" CRLF
       zzz,yyy,xxx

   6.  Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
       should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:

       "aaa","b CRLF
       bb","ccc" CRLF
       zzz,yyy,xxx

   7.  If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
       appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
       another double quote.  For example:

       "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
```

So your formatting is correct and aslong as Excel shows the file correctly I wouldn't mind about the double "double quotes"